# Cache multiplication operation

Tags: c++, caching

I have to raise many numbers in base 50 at power X (X anywhere between 1 and 300).
The numbers are stored as bignums.

My question is: because I will multiply lots of times two bignums digit by digit (base 50) will it be faster to cache this multiplications?

So, every time I multiply `a[]` with `b[]` I will have to do `a[i]*b[j]` many times where `a[i]` and `b[j]` are base 50 numbers.

I was thinking instead of actually doing `a[i]*b[j]` each time, wouldn't it be faster to create a matrix beforehand: `prod[50][50]`, where `prod[i][j] = i*j`. I will then have something like `prod[a[i]][b[j]]`.

Is reading from memory faster then actually doing the multiplication?

**Quick example if my question is not clear:**

Instead of:

```
for(int i=1; i<=100; ++i){
   sum += 50*30;
   sum += 37*20;
}
```

Is this faster:

```
for(int i=1; i<=100; ++i){
   sum += prod[50][30];
   sum += prod[37][20];
}
```

?

Comment: Why not convert numbers to binary representation in the first place?

Comment: And how would that help? Wouldn't it take more time to convert to binary and back to base 50? Note that the numbers are large, like 50^1000. Can't be stored in a single variable.

Comment: Why base 50? It's common to use a larger base when implementing bignums (up to `sqrt(MAXINT)`), as that allows doing more with fewer operations and less memory. Even if you need base 50 output at the end, I'd wager this could save enough time that it's still a net win after base 50 conversion.

Comment: I also have to output the result in base 50, so I thought not doing base-conversion might save some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes, most likely.

Long answer: It depends. It is probably faster to calculate a multiplication in cache than it is to fetch a large number from memory if it's not in cache.

You really need to implement the caching and benchmark it against the "no cache" to see what you get.

Bear in mind also that powers can be calculated more efficiently than just multiplying, e.g, if we want y = x<sup>5</sup>, instead of calculating `y = x * x * x * x * x`, we can calculate `x2 = x * x;`, then `y = x2 * x2 * x;`, which is only four multiplications instead of five. If you have x<sup>300</sup>, you could make some substantial savings by using that same scheme several times over (calculating x4 and x16 etc).

Comment: Yes, I am already using logarithmic exponation - complexity log2(power).